# Py2exe error converting tkinter to exe - 'module' object has no attribute 'tcldir'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, py2exe

I am having trouble converting a python3 script with tkinter into exe using py2exe.

*Without tkinter the program is successfully converted into exe.*

I have tried creating both normal and bundled exe but it throws the following exception everytime:

```
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup_py2exe_assist.py", line 14, in <module>
    'bundle_files': 1,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 173, in analyze
    target.analyze(mf)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 74, in analyze
    modulefinder.run_script(self.script)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 86, in run_script
    self._scan_code(mod.__code__, mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
    self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 341, in _find_and_load
    self._load_module(loader, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 372, in _load_module
    self._add_module(name, mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\dllfinder.py", line 209, in _add_module
    self.hook(mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\dllfinder.py", line 206, in hook
    mth(self, mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\hooks.py", line 259, in hook_tkinter
    tcl_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(fix.tcldir, ".."))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tcldir'
```

To be clear, I want to include tkinter. Please help figure out the problem as I could not find a solution to this problem anywhere. By the way, is anyone having the same problem as I have?

Comment: Perhaps try some other converters. There are even online ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `python 3.6` which I presume you are doing the same. I also experienced this problem and settled with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which can be installed using `pip`. This fully supports 3.6  and previous versions but what I like more is the `--noconsole` argument which doesn't show the standard i/o window (so you only get your `tkinter` window)

EDIT:
Sorry, just looked at the file paths and saw you are using `python 3.4`. This may mean my answer is irrelevant :'(

Comment: Thanks, pyinstaller really worked for me :-)  but it has increased the program startup time. :-(

Comment: That's weird! I thought it would do the opposite (as it doesn't have to go via the Python interpreter).